# Triangle problem (only know 1 side and y-axis coordinates of 2 points)

Tags: analytic-geometry, triangles

I have a triangle problem that I am in desperate need of help with with.
Here is what I know ...

the triangle is mapped on a graph where I only know y-axis coordinates for 2 points, the length of one side, and a percentage of a second side as per details below:

the 3 y-axis point coordinates (A,B,C) Ay=2.23, By=3.39, Cy=???

the 3 x-axis point coordinates of Ax, Bx, Cx are all unknown

the length of the side A to B is 1.16

the length of the side B to C=261.8% of the length of A to C

don't know any angles

I need to determine ...

the value of coordinate of Cy and/or the length of the side from A to C or alternatively, the length of the side from B to C
Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Something doesn't make sense here: we have three points, *each of them* being an ordered pair $\;(x,y)\;$ , then: what are $\;p_1,p_2,p_x\;$ ?? I thought each of these $\;p_i\;$ was *an ordered pair*  since you call them "points"...

Comment: i only know the y value for each point .. which i referred to as p.

Comment: Well, then I seriously advice you re-edit your question and call the triangles vertices $\;A=(A_x,A_y)\;,\;B=(B_x,B_y)\;,\;C=(C_x,C_y)\;$ and etc., or something like this, because as it is now it's pretty confusing....

Comment: question edited, per your suggestion.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Draw a diagram in the plane, with the constant lines $\;y=2.23\;,\;y=3.39\;$ (note that the distance between these two lines is precisely $\;1.16\;$ ...!) .

On these lines the point $\;A,B\;$ are located. Now, taking into account the length $\;AB\;$  we get the points $\;A,B\;$ are on thesame vertical line, so we can already determine that

$$A=(x_0\,,\,2.23)\;\;,\;\;B=(x_0\,,\,3.39)\;\;(\text{same abscissa}\;\;x_0\;\;\text{for both points !})$$

Since we're given $\;BC=2.2618\cdot AC$ , it's clear point $\;C\; $ "is on the side of point$\;A\;$ " , but this is a rather blurry notion.

But there's no way to determine the coordinate of $\;C\;$ as it could be on the right side of the line $\;x=x_0\;$ or on its left, so the lengths $\;AC\;,\;BC\;$ cannot be known